# A lower bound for number of cycles in a grid graph

Tags: graph-theory, upper-lower-bounds

Consider a rectangular grid graph of size $m \times n$, like following $4 \times 7$:

[image]

Fix $m \geq 2$, I'm trying to proof that exist a positive constant $\epsilon > 0$ such that the number of cycles of the rectangular grid of size $m \times n$ with $n \geq 2$ named $C(m,n)$ is at least $2^{\epsilon \cdot n}$, i.e. $C(m,n) \in 2^{\Omega(n)}$.

**Idea:** My conjecture is that $\epsilon =1$ and to demonstrate this I'm thinking in assign to each binary number of lenght $n$ a specific cycle in the grid such that the correspondence is injective and then I will have $C(m,n) \geq 2^n$ for every $n$ but I'm stack. Any hint?

**Edit:** $m$ and $n$ can be equal (square grid) and as big if it is necessary.

Comment: 1). "proof" --> "prove"
2). I see $\epsilon$ only once

Comment: no disrespect, but these kinds of questions and interactions are why I almost entirely look just at bountied questions.

Comment: @CrisPaint As it stands, if the statement holds for $\epsilon=1$, it also holds for $\epsilon = 10^{-1000}$. In fact, we can drop the restriction "$>0$" and it works also for $\epsilon =-42$ or $\epsilon=i$

Comment: Is your image a $3\times 6$ or a $4\times 7$?

Comment: @CrisPaint It seems you don't get our complaints. Your statement is of the form "There exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $2+2=4$".

Comment: @CrisPaint you have to be trolling

Comment: You are completely right @mathworker21 and Hagen , an error of writing that's my fault and I omitted, sorry. I corrected the statement in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a proof without words for $2^n$ cycles

[image]

Comment: Finest thing I've seen all day.

Comment: Very simple assignment, it's perfect. Thanks a lot.